# Add attribute to tag for all Wordpress pages

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I add an attribute to the H1 tag for all my Wordpress site pages using PHP?

Desired Outcome:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">Title of Article</h1>
```

Comment: You can do it with JS, if it meet your requirement I can suggest you way using JS.

Comment: I did it easily with jQuery. But it didn't appear on Google structured data testing tool. So I really don't see the point of using JS.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code

```
 $html = new DOMDocument();
    $html->loadHtml('filename');
    $nodes = $html->getElementsByTagName('h1');
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $node->setAttribute('itemprop','name');
    }
    $txt = $html->saveHTML();
```

Let me know if it works!

**EDIT:**

```
 <?php

$html = '<h1>Title of Article</h1>';

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHtml($html);
    $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h1');
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
            $node->setAttribute('itemprop','name');
    }

$html = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $html;
```

Using this code you can see the results. Just paste above code in blank php file and run in browser to see results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping out. Sorry, I am a PHP noob. How should I add this to functions.php?

Comment: I am not sure how you are displaying HTML. I am not much into wordpress

Comment: I have edited answer. You can accept it if it solves your problem to help others

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the very first `h1` in the post which dynamically displays the name of the post or page defined in the backend?

That should be possible using this code in the page or post template (which could be `index.php`or `page.php` or `post.php` or `single.php` etc.) at the position where the where title is displayed by default (must be inside the Wordpress `loop`):

```
<h1 itemprop="name"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Comment: My title tag is different from the h1 so I won't be able to use this solution

Comment: well, that's  just an example, taking the code you posted, but of course you can apply that to *any* tag in '*any* template file